# Cocos2d Android - Combining CCGLSurfaceView and other views (eg. Admob or Imageview)

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob, cocos2d-android

I'm stuck in the problem to get a combined `CCGLSurfaceView` working together with other android native views like an `ImageView` for example.
I started to develop a game using Cocos2D and I'm planning to add advert via admob in it later. Therefore I want to run the `CCGLSurfaceView` (**OpenGl** View for my game) at the top and the advert should be displayed below it.

I already tried several things like adding both views manually (not via XML) to a relative layout but keep getting `null pointers` and my app force closes.

I also tried [this](http://rx-games.com/admob-adverts-on-surfaceview-no-xml-tutorial/) tutorial where they explain how to integrate `admob` into a `OpenGl SurfaceView`. But still it didn't work, maybe it's because I'm using Cocos2d?

I don't know, can someone help me out with this (maybe cocos2d specific) problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need your code (putting a link to what you based yourself on is not very helpful in the overall)

My approach is to define all this in the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.pixelrain.opengl.GLSurfaceViewChipmunk android:id="@+id/composed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAd"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the GLSurfaceViewChipmunk is what you replace by cocos2d.

and then in the application

```
 private void InitAdView()
    {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutAd);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AppSettings.AdmobAppId);

        ...set your add listener

        // Add the adView to the layout
        layout.addView(adView);
```

Comment: Sorry Guys, i made a little stupid mistake... and just found it now! So it is working (if you follow the tutorial).So if anyone has a problem with arranging OpenGL Views with other android views, he can follow the tutorial i posted above.